# Oracle SQL. How to make a case when statement where the 'THEN' outputs a letter followed by 4 digits

Tags: sql, oracle

So I want to create a case statement which outputs something like 
case when 'field name' is not null 
then "    "

I want the output to be like 'R0001' 'R0002' 'R1234' etc. So it starts with R for a maximum of four digits afterwards.

I tried to use `regexp_like [a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}` but I cant get it to work.

```
select distinct field_name
     , CASE WHEN field_name is not null
            THEN regexp_like [a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}        
            ELSE null
       End as field_name1    
  from table;;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide sample data (in a format that it can be easily used by readers of the forum) and the desired outcome. It also helps to show what you have already tried.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by the question. You want to create a new string that outputs "R' followed by a random 4 digits... or "R" followed by an incrementing sequence of 4 digits? Regular expressions are typically used for finding repeating string not generating them...

Comment: if my understanding is correct, you might also want to look into REGEX_SUBSTR. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303

Answer (score 2):

There are several syntax errors. In particular, the use of `regexp_like` is incorrect.

```
  select
distinct field_name
       , CASE
            WHEN field_name is not null AND regexp_like(field_name, '[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}')
            THEN '<whatever>'        
            ELSE null
         END as field_name1    
    from "table"
       ;
```

Btw, the regular expression does not match the description, as it matches *exactly* 4 digits (instead of *up to 4*). The latter would be handled by `[a-zA-Z]\d{1,4}`.

***Update***

To map `field_name` values to a set of names obeying the pattern `R\d{4}` with consecutive numbering starting at 1 use one of the following queries:

Variant 1: `field_name` is an AK for `table`

```
select field_name
     , 'R' || to_char(rownum, 'FM0009') anon_field_name
  from "table"
     ;
```

Variant 2: `table` may contain duplicates of `field_name`

```
select field_name
     , 'R' || to_char(rownum, 'FM0009') anon_field_name
  from (
           select
         distinct field_name 
             from "table"
       ) t_names
     ;
```

The queries are specific to oracle, but virtually every rdbms has a function / pseudocolumn equivalent to `ROWNUM` and offers string formatting features to pad leading zeroes.

***Randomized mapping***

The mapping between `field_names` and numbers in the anonymized field names reflects the order in which the records from `table` occur in the resultset. This order is not guaranteed as long as you do not specify an `order by` clause. So technically, the output is not predictable.

However, if you have the impression that the record order does not change (sufficiently) across queries, add (pseudo)random numbers to the resultset and order it accordingly:

```
  select field_name
       , 'R' || to_char(rownum, 'FM0009') anon_field_name
    from (
              select field_name
                   , dbms_random.value  code
                from (
                         select
                       distinct field_name
                           from "table"
                     ) t_names
         ) t_withrandom
order by t_withrandom.code
     ;
```

Again, the method to generate (pseudo)random numbers is specific to Oracle, but all other vendors' products have equivalent features.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. So I have a field which needs to be anonymised for data release. so 'field_name' is used to create 'anon_field_name'. The anon_field_name should be formatted like 'R0001', 'R0002' etc Starting with R and being a maximum of 4 digits long. So when field_name is not null it needs to be assigned a anon id code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It's exactly what I want. Do you know how to make the numbers randomise. My output is predictable

Comment: The mapping between field_names and numbers reflects the order in which the records from `table` occur in the resultset. This order is not guaranteed as long as you do not specify an order by clause. So technically, your output is not predictable.